# Why is the Klein-Gordan equation linear and what does that mean for the interaction of scalar fields?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

While Dirac's equation can be seen as the relativistic Schrödinger equation for fermions, the Klein-Gordon equation refers to bosons. It is of the form 
($\partial^2 +m^2)\phi = 0$, where $\partial^2 = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} - \overline{\nabla}^2$ and $\phi$ is the scalar field with a wave-like solution, i. e. the solution is of the form
$\phi(\overline{x},t) = \sum_\overline{p} a_\overline{p} e^{-i(E_\overline{p}t-\overline{p}\overline{x})}$.

The equation is now, why is that equation linear?
The definition of linearity is the following: A mapping $f: V \rightarrow W$ is called linear, if for any vectors $\overline{u},\overline{v} \in V$ and for any number $c$ the following is true:
 i) $f(c\overline{u}) = c \cdot f(\overline{u})$
ii) $f(\overline{u} + \overline{v}) = f(\overline{u}) + f(\overline{v})$.
Only, what is $\overline{u}, \overline{v}$ in the context of of the Klein-Gordon equation? I guess it is e. g. $u = \phi$ and $v = \phi'$, which would make the mapping indeed linear (, right?).
And why would an inhomogenous mapping, i. e. the right-hand side of the Klein-Gordon equation is non-zero, is a non-linear mapping? Consider ($\partial^2 +m^2)\phi = const \cdot \phi^3$. Why is this not a linear mapping?
Apparently, linearity is equivalent to have scalar field interactions, whereas non-linearity implies no interaction. Why is that so?

Thank you in advance for any hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we say a particular equation is *linear*, we mean that it follows the **principle of superposition**:

> For any two solutions $\phi$ and $\psi$ of the equation, $a\phi+b\psi$ is also a solution, for any constant $a$ and $b$.

Since $\partial^2(a\phi+b\psi)=a\partial^2\phi+b\partial^2\psi$ from the basic rules of differentiation, and since $m^2$ is just a constant, clearly $m^2(a\phi+b\psi)=am^2\phi+bm^2\psi$, we can easily show that, for two fields $\phi$ and $\psi$, if $(\partial^2+m^2)\phi=0$ and $(\partial^2+m^2)\psi=0$, this implies that $(\partial^2+m^2)(a\phi+b\psi)=0$.

In contrast, the equation $(\partial^2+m^2)\phi=k\phi^3$ does **not** follow this principle, since

$$(a\phi+b\psi)^3=a^3\phi^3+3a^2b\phi^2\psi+3ab^2\phi\psi^2+b^3\psi^3$$

meaning in particular that

$$(a\phi+b\psi)^3\neq a\phi^3+b\psi^3$$

so we can't add together two solutions of that equation and get another solution of the equation.

> Apparently, linearity is equivalent to have scalar field interactions, whereas non-linearity implies no interaction. Why is that so?

I don't know where you heard this, and I also don't know that this is true in general. It's hard to know exactly what is being referred to here without context, but in general, in a Lagrangian, *nonlinear* terms are the ones which represent interactions.

Comment: Hi probably_someone and thank you for your answer. It helped a lot.  The linearity-interaction statement was taken from the book "Quantum Field Theory for the Gifted Amateur" by T. Lancaster and S. J. Blundell and indeed stood in the context of the Lagrange formalism. However, you linked superposition to linearity and I know from quantum chemistry, that when a groundstate of a fermionic system is described by a superposition of Slater determinants, we have fermionic interaction; a single Slater determinant implies no interaction. Probably, this is analogue to the bosonic case. Again, thanks!